# Activating/Adding sidebar in lightning tabs?

Tags: lightning-experience, administration, sidebar

I have created some custom components (in classic: visualforce area), that are displayed in the sidebar in classic.

I am facing the challenge when moving to Lightning as the tabs pages such as opportunity dont have a component section, like the other pages do(home, record and app page)

Do i need to create an app page to replace the opportunity tab?

If yes, is there a way to bring into this page the list view drop down?

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? Were you able to achieve this?

Comment: No, i ended up adding the component in record layout and im home page, but i still don't know if it ossa possible to display it on the record tab